# Integer solutions to $2x^2+5x+y^2=19$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$$2x^2+5x+y^2=19$$

Don't know how to approach the problem. Similar equations required factoring after the completing a square or a similar trick. I don't see the possibility of that here though. Hints? Answers?

Comment: I don't see how this helps..

Comment: Actually, multiply through by $8,$ complete the square in $x,$ it is an ellipse that does have some integer points. http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: There are only a relatively small number of possibilities to work through. $(x,y) = \{(2,\pm1),(-3,\pm4)\}$

Comment: Isn't this just an ellipse?  That gives you a finite number of possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$\begin{align}19-2x^2-5x=y^2\ge 0&\Rightarrow 2x^2+5x-19\le 0\\&\Rightarrow \frac{-5-\sqrt{177}}{4}\le x\le\frac{-5+\sqrt{177}}{4}\\&\Rightarrow -4\le x\le 2\end{align}$$

Comment: Are these types of exercises often solved using this method or is it just handy to use in this situation?

Comment: Because of the geometry (ellipse) there are only finitely many candidates. So it is reasonable to put bounds on the candidates, and then test them all.

Comment: @JohnDoe: As André Nicolas comments, you can use the method for example when you have $ax^2+bx+cy^2=d$ where $a,b$ are positive.

Answer (score 1):

The equation with small numbers allows easy calculations. As a simple quadratic equation we have $4x = -5 ±\sqrt{177-8y^2}$. There are just four possibilities:
y = ±1, ±2, ±3, ±4 and only ±1 and ±4 are good. Thus $4x = -5 ±13$ and 
$4x = -5 ±7$. Finally the only solutions are (x, y) = (2, ±1) and (-3, ±4)