# Diophantine solutions to a large geometric figure

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have a related question to one I've read today, see:
 [Integer solutions to $2x^2+5x+y^2=19$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301746/integer-solutions-to-2x25xy2-19)

The integers solution are part of an ellipse, with an obvious finite number of $x$. What I would like to know is, when we have a large ellipse so that computing each $x$ would be disastrous by hand, is there any method to cut the possibilities down, or provide an exact answer for an ellipse? Or are there only approximation algorithms that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $y$ are positive integers you can write:
$$5x+y^2\equiv 1\pmod 2$$
But the acceptable values of $x$ are $1,2,3$ because $5x<19$ while the acceptable values of $y$ are $1,2,3,4$ because $y^2<19$.
You can consider two systems:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
5x\equiv 0\pmod 2\\
y^2\equiv 1\pmod 2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
And
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
5x\equiv 1\pmod 2\\
y^2\equiv 0\pmod 2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
In the first systems the acceptable   value of $x$ is only $2$ and the acceptable values of $y$ are $1,3$. In the second system the acceptable values of $x$ are $1,3$ while $y$ are $2,4$. Now you can control the solitions.
Edit:
to find also the negative values you can consider the equation of second degree in $x$:
$$2x^2+5x+y^2-19=0$$
The discriminant of equation is $\Delta=177-8y^2$
but $$177-8y^2\ge 0$$
therefore the accetable values of $y$ are:${{-4,-3,....,3,4}}$
but $$177-8y^2=k^2$$
and the only values that solve the equation are $y=$ $\pm 1$ and $\pm 4$.

Comment: Why did you ignore the $2x^2$ and why did you use mod 2? Why only positive integers?

Comment: I ignore $x^2$ because I use the $mod 2$ but I could use also $mod 5$ and to ignore $5x$. And I found only positive solutions as I wrote in my answer

Comment: Would finding negative solutions me more complicated? From what you've told me, we can use $2x^2 + y^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$, or is it $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$? Would we have $5$ systems for $\pmod 5$?

Comment: Using $mod 5$ we obtain the equation $2x^2+y^2\equiv 4\pmod 5$ and we have analyse  $5$ systems

Comment: Ah, this is getting interesting. Each system would consist of what equations though? Sorry that I am asking so many questions. You can always direct me to related theorems behind your answer.

Comment: Each system consists of two equation for example: $2x^2\equiv 0, y^2\equiv 4 \pmod 5$ is a system.

Comment: Yes, but what would the other 4 systems contain? You paired 0 and 4, what are the remaining 4 pairs?

Comment: The other four systems are $2x^2\equiv 1, y^2\equiv 3\pmod 5$,$2x^2\equiv 2, y^2\equiv 2\pmod 5$, $2x^2\equiv 3,y^2\equiv 1\pmod 5$ and $2x^2\equiv 0,y^2\equiv 4\pmod 5$